# How do you create a custom stream wrapper?

Tags: 8

I am trying to create a new custom stream wrapper. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is something I have worked on more than a year ago https://gist.github.com/ivanjaros/fcf7ed50fbb98024464a29cfdcb01167
I have written [Google Cloud Storage stream wrapper](https://gist.github.com/ivanjaros/4ec2103fb099d6a8945e6b560d31c13a) last week which is much better than this but it is a bit different use case(I think that gist is 95% accurate to what I have now). Anyway, you'll need to provide the S3 service to it on your own. I'd suggest to go over the code and maybe get inspired but I wouldn't use it as is.

Also see this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2830828